# Which animatronic is "Fred Bear"?

Tags: five-nights-series

I hear my friends talking about an animatronic called "Fred Bear". I cant tell if this is supposed to be Golden Freddy or another one?

Please explain to me who this "Fred Bear" is?

Answer (score 4):

There is no "Fred bear."

Certain YouTubers and bloggers use this as a nickname. It usually refers to "Freddy."

Answer (score 4):

When people talk about, they refer to one of the first anamatronics in the original Fredbear's Family Diner which is a predecessor to Freddy Fazbear.

While it's theorized he is Golden Freddy due to his appearance of golden and purple bowtie it's not 100% confirmed either way. In FNAF4 he does appears in nightmare form on night 5 and is seen in the 8-bit minigames between nights in FNAF4 and the Stage01 minigame in FNAF3.

Answer (score 1):

Fred bear is possibly golden Freddy. Some of us believe that Scott Cawthon will explain in Fnaf sister location 2 (Fnaf 6). I may be wrong but if you play the first Fnaf and try custom nights, put in the animatronics order 1 9 8 7 and golden Freddy will appear. In the same look as Fred bear. If you try this then be careful because if you let golden Freddy's jumpscare end then you go all the way back to night 1. Another way to see golden Freddy is (really rare) he appears under the poster of Freddy (still Fnaf 1) then under the desk. Again he will jumpscare you and crash your game but there is no way to make that happen on your own accord.

Answer (score 1):

Fredbear is Golden Freddy, but with a purple attire (purple bowtie and hat) instead of black and actually has an endoskeleton. He doubles as an animatronic and suit worn by employees at Fredbear's Family Diner. His spring locks (if they were triggered) pull an entire endoskeleton out of the fabric costume and under the fabric for entertainment by robot. This wouldn't have been a bad thing until we found out about "a spring lock malfunction at the sister location" (just letting you know that the "sister location" mentioned is NOT the 5th game's location, but the 4th game's location) from phone guy in the third game. He was first introduced to the series in the 3rd game, in one of the minigames, and was a major antagonist and profile in the 4th game. In the 4th game, set in time during the second game and before the first, completing the game gives you a cutscene of a kid (the protagonist) getting shoved into Fredbear's mouth by his older brother in a Foxy mask and his friends (all in other antagonist masks). This means that Fredbear is indeed an animatronic, but discovered and named in the 4th game.